# "Error DEP6957 Failed to connect to device using Universal Authentication" when deploying Unity app to Hololens emulator

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens-emulator

I've been working in a Unity app with Hololens emulator in Visual Studio 2017 in Windows Pro, and it was working great until last night where I started to get the following issue every time that I try to deploy my application into the Hololens emulator:

**Error DEP6957 : Failed to connect to device '[device_ip]' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings.**

I've tried to do the following things without success:

- Clean/rebuild solution
- Checked 'uninstall/install' checkbox in the UWP project settings
- Deleted Hololens virtual machine
- Uncheck/check Hyper-v feature (and restart PC after each try)
- Restarted computer

No luck. Sometimes, I am able to make it work, but after 30 seconds to 1 minute, the hololens emulator gets frozen and then it closes itself; again, this was working fine until last night, and I have not installed anything different, unless an automatic windows update did something. This happens with all the applications, and they run just fine in the Unity player.

I would appreciate your help on this, I just don't think the only solution is to uninstall/install Visual studio and all its components, it makes no sense, since everything was ok.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I've just noticed that if I connect the laptop to the internet by using an ethernet cable, it works, it only fails in WIFI, have you seen that before? I also have another UWP that I deploy remotely to a raspberry and it also works only with ethernet, but both of them were used to work in wifi? any idea?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the folder that Unity builds the solution to and then rebuilding in Unity?

Comment: I tried that without any luck. What is weird is that if I plugged the laptop to the ethernet (not Wifi), it works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: I found this thread that has a couple of suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578467/visual-studio-failed-deploy-to-hololens-error-dep6957-failed-to-connect-to-de